# Need to iterate through two lists and spit out a final list but being able to start on any element of one of the lists

Tags: python, list, loops, format

Little problem in Python, first time post, looking for help for a little project
So I have two lists:

```
list1=(True,False,True,False,True,True,False,True,False,True,False,True)

list2=["A","A#","B","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#",]
```

I need to generate a 3rd list which is a result of the following function:

pick a random starting element in list 2 and then compare that to each element of list1 starting at element 0. if element is true, spit out the respective element value from list2.

so to make an example, user picks element 2 of list2 ("B") as input, the output should be (preferably without the quotes, would be awesome to see the code with and without quote stripping):
`"B", "C#", "D#", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#"`

Comment: are you sure your output is ok?i guess there should be ```A``` character instead of ```A#```

Comment: Yes positive the output is correct :) this is for a music application and the idea is to allow the user to pick any starting note and then the list of true and falses make up the dna of a major ionian scale. So in essence you should be able to pick any starting note, and then list1 spits out the relevant related notes in correct sequence. Check out @Eddoasso answers, its literally perfect. Haven't run it yet, but just reading it looks like he nailed it on the head. beautiful use of pop and N positions shifts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My aproach to this problem would be:

- Shift left the list 2, by N positions as read from input from user.

-Iterate over list 1, and if value is true, add element I of list2 to final list.

```
list1=(True,False,True,False,True,True,False,True,False,True,False,True)

list2=["A","A#","B","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#",]

#user needs to input something to continue
raw_input = input('how many positions?\n')

##shifting the list2 N positions
for i in range(int(raw_input)):
    #we remove the first element in the list and add it back to the end
    element = list2.pop(0)
    list2.append(element)

##Iterating over list 1, and if value is true, add element in index I to a new list.

#creating final list
final = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    val = list1[i]
    if(val):
        final.append(list2[i])

print(final)
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! you solved it! This is perfect, the trick here was using N positions to 'pop' them one by one to the end of the list in order, and then the beautiful if statement nested in the for loop spits it out perfectly. Flawless sir! This is used for a musical app so the logic behind it is that a user 'picks a starting note' and the elements true and false spell out a major ionian scale based on a bool type existence of the note of the available 12 notes in music :)

Answer (score 0):

i believe you have a mistake in referring to `A#` and also `D#` in your final list. i think you should refer to `A` and `D`. anyway ,I think the below code will help you.

```
import random
list1=(True,False,True,False,True,True,False,True,False,True,False,True)

list2=["A","A#","B","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#",]
getRandomElement = list2[random.randrange(0,len(list2))]
finalList = []
if getRandomElement in list2:
    getIndex  = list2.index(getRandomElement)
    for index,value in enumerate(list2):
        if(list1[index]):
            finalList.append(value)

print(finalList)
```

**Output** (with respect to present list in your question)

```
['A', 'B', 'C#', 'D', 'E', 'F#', 'G#']
```